# Delete migration in flyway

Tags: flyway

I'm experiencing the following issue:

```
org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Validate failed: Detected applied migration not resolved locally: 1.44
```

That happened when I understood that the data that I added in 1.44 is invalid and I don't want to deal with it on old environments, but on new environments I don't want this data. I want the data that I will insert within new migration(e.g. 1.48).

- If I change old migration it will fail on old envs due to checksum;
- If I leave it, on new envs I will have invalid data from 1.44;

How can I delete it so that I accomplish what I need and not to get an error? What's the correct way?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This questions is related to [Best pratice: How to modify flyway migration script after it has been used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35489069/best-pratice-how-to-modify-flyway-migration-script-after-it-has-been-used)

The basic answer is: **don't delete once it's been applied**

It doesn't matter if during the migration process some intermediary state isn't exactly what you want, as long as the final one (1.48 in your case) is correct.

Now if you *really* need to delete this migration, ask yourself whether replacing it with an empty file could also do the job. If yes you could then follow the advice I gave here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35491545/350428

Now if that's still not enough and you *really really* need to delete this migration, delete the file and patch up the `flyway_schema_history` table by hand to make it consistent again. This is risk-prone and should be an absolute last resort solution.

Answer (score 1):

you can **UNDO** your migration: [UNDO flyway migration](https://flywaydb.org/getstarted/undo)

Comment: This is only available for paid version.